# Convert Array to String in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to convert an array output to string for later manipulation and visibility.

For example I have an array {681120;953160;909420;16300}. 
How would I go about converting that into a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArrayLoop()

    Dim ArrList As Variant
    Dim ArrItem As Variant
    Dim Result As String

    ArrList = Array("681120", "953160", "909420", "16300")

    Result = ""

    For Each ArrItem In ArrList
        If Result = "" Then
            Result = ArrItem
        Else: Result = Result & "_" & ArrItem
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```